# Datatables Multi Filter Select - each column is treated differently

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables.net to display 5 columns and about 2,000 rows.  I've applied this [API initialization](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) to my code and it works but the filter drop-downs aren't that helpful because of the amount and types of data in my table.

Here are the column headings for that data I'm working with:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Post Date</th>
  <th>Post Title</th>
  <th>Author Name</th>
  <th>Categories</th>
  <th>Page Views</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

**Post Date**: contains almost every day of 2012 formatted like "Thu 11/29/12" "Wed 11/28/12" etc.  I'd like for the filter drop down to only contain the abbreviations for the seven days of the week.  This way we can filter for all Monday posts etc.

**Post Title**: contains roughly 2,000 unique blog post titles so there is nothing to filter on here.  Don't show a filter dropdown at all.

**Author**: many different authors submit posts so this filter drop-down should build from the data in the column.

**Categories**: contains comma-separated short lists like "News, Events, Sports" or "Deals, Weekend" or maybe just one category "Nightlife" etc.  There is a finite number of categories and these won't change so a hardcoded list would work.  I don't need every combination of the categories.  Just to be able to filter for posts categorized as "Deals" regardless of what "Deals" has been paired with.

**Page Views**: contains the different numeric values so no filter needs to be shown.  Could get greedy here and ask for filters when views are greater than 100, 500, 1000 etc but it isn't necessary.

I'm just learning jquery and that is why I was so excited to see how easily Datatables can be implemented to give a professional looking and functioning view of a lot of information.  However, I find that I am unable to really customize other's work so I am hoping a kind Stack Overflow user would be able to edit the table initialization code (seen here: http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) to work with my table how I outlined above.

Your answer might be that this is too custom of a job and would require an amount of time that isn't typical for a free Stack Overflow solution.  However, I think others might find this example useful if you post some code.  Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plugin helped me out: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/ especially the checkbox example: http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/checkbox.html